# .fadeToggle() stops after second loop

Tags: jquery, transition

I'm trying to write an event that uses a fade transition to display text after clicking on an element. The code seems to be working with one pass, but I'd like it to be an infinite loop of toggling/untoggling the text. After toggling in the text once and then toggling out once, `.fadeToggle()` seems to stop reacting, yet everything else seemingly functions as normal. I needed this method because `.visuallyhidden` is a must for screen reader purposes (and fade transitions for aesthetic purposes).

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.CEL-clickToggleReaction').addClass('visuallyhidden');
    $('.CEL-clickToggleAction').bind('click', openReaction);

    function openReaction() {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.CEL-clickToggleReaction').removeClass('visuallyhidden');
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.CEL-clickToggleReaction').hide();
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.CEL-clickToggleReaction').fadeToggle(500);
        $(this).attr('class', 'CEL-clickToggleActionOpen');
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.CEL-clickToggleActionOpen').unbind();
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.CEL-clickToggleActionOpen').bind('click', closeReaction);

    }


    function closeReaction() {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.CEL-clickToggleReaction').fadeToggle(500);
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.CEL-clickToggleReaction').delay().queue(function (next) {
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.CEL-clickToggleReaction').addClass('visuallyhidden');
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.CEL-clickToggleReaction').show();
        });
        $(this).attr('class', 'CEL-clickToggleAction');
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.CEL-clickToggleAction').unbind();
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.CEL-clickToggleAction').bind('click', openReaction);

    }
});
```

Comment: I'm so happy for you you come to StackOverflow :) I'm sure you'll get some nice advices how to write better code! Welcome

Comment: A little bit aside from your question look how your code might look using chaining where possible and with better performance when stop searching the same nodes over and over again but instead cache them into variable:  http://jsfiddle.net/LPeVw/

Comment: Thank you @kidwon! Fortunately, I'm not the last person in the line of development/cleaning the code. Ha!

Comment: Feel free to fill the gap of the `HTML` and the `css` in the fiddle I've provided so that people can estimate what's the problem indeed and help you.

Comment: @kidwon I've added my CSS and HTML here: http://jsfiddle.net/LPeVw/1/ . I've removed the second .parent() for the sake of having it in the fiddle. The reason I had it reach up twice was because I have the reaction and action nested in columns, but they aren't necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your input! I discovered that the issue I was having was with .queue(). I simply add .dequeue() after that function and it's working now.

Thank you!!

Edit: I actually changed the entire way the code worked and will share it here. This is (what I believe) a nice way to handle fade toggles while still keeping the content screen reader accessible (assuming you have some sort of visually hidden in your code).

```
$(document).ready(function () {


        $('.CEL-clickToggleReaction').addClass('visuallyhidden').css('opacity', 0);


        $('.CEL-clickToggleAction').click(function(){
            var reaction = $(this).parent().parent().find('.CEL-clickToggleReaction'),
                opacity = reaction.css('opacity');

                if (reaction.hasClass('visuallyhidden')) {

                    reaction.removeClass('visuallyhidden').animate({opacity: (opacity==1?0:1)});

                }

                else {

                    reaction.animate({opacity: (opacity==1?0:1)}).queue(function (next) {

                        reaction.addClass('visuallyhidden').dequeue();

                    });

                }
        });   
});
```